# Python: How to split the name of the csv file in directory

Tags: python, file

I have few files in the directory having names as 'salary.csv_result.csv', 'cost.csv_result.csv'...etc.. How can I split the name of the CSV files?  Please suggest how to change all the file names from the directory. My expected name of the files are

```
 'salary.csv', 'cost.csv'...etc..

for files in os.listdir(files_dir):
    file_name = files[:files.find('.')]
```

Comment: Please clarify.  Do you want to rename the files from `salary.csv_result.csv` to `salary.csv` or just extract that name?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to implement this feature” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Please specify the output you want.  Please explain how your current coding attempt doesn't satisfy you.  Your description appears to describe a straightforward application of string processing, covered by any tutorial on Python strings: `split`, slicing, `find`, etc.  If your manipulation involves file-specific operations, you might find the `os` methods on file names to be useful.

Comment: @Mark Tolonem I want to save the file as 'salary.csv'

Comment: Is the '_result.csv' sort of a constant suffix here for all the csv files, or the suffix is gonna vary??

Answer (score 1):

This code will do it.

```
for files in os.listdir(files_dir): 
  # Better to call this filename than filename
  splits = files.split('.')
  # The assertions are optional
  assert splits[1] == 'csv_result'
  assert splits[2] == 'csv'
  filename = splits[0] +'.csv'
  # ... filename will have the requested form
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply. One last question, if am saving the filename in another directory, the content of the file is missing. Please suggest.

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question, as that is a different matter. Be sure to read ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.